# jQuery remove all characters but numbers and decimals

Tags: javascript, replace, currency

```
var price = "$23.03";
var newPrice = price.replace('$', '')
```

This works, but price can also be such as:

```
var price = "23.03 euros";
```

and many many other currencies.

Is there anyway that I could leave only numbers and decimal(.)?

Comment: How is this related to jQuery? This is pure javascript and in no way uses the jQuery library.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looking up the documentation for `replace`, for example?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var newPrice = price.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
```

No jQuery needed. You will also need to check if there is only one decimal point though, like this:

```
var decimalPoints = newPrice.match(/\./g);

// Annoyingly you have to check for null before trying to
// count the number of matches.
if (decimalPoints && decimalPoints.length > 1) {
    // do whatever you do when input is invalid.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newprice = price.replace( /\D+$/, '');
```