# Strip non numeric characters from h1

Tags: jquery

I need to strip all letters from a h1 with a certain class so that

```
<h1 class="hole">1st Hole</h1>
```

Becomes

```
<h1 class="hole">1</h1>
```

And this would replicate on each page, 2nd Hole, 3rd Hole etc

Comment: Your question and title conflict. Do you want to remove all letters (`a-z` and `A-Z`), or all non-numeric (i.e. digit) characters (anything that isn't `0-9`)? You example removes a space character, which indicates the latter, which agrees with the title but conflicts with the question's content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery remove all characters but numbers and decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464306/jquery-remove-all-characters-but-numbers-and-decimals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the receiver function of **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to accomplish your job efficiently. And additionally `^\d` matches the non-numeric, so we are just replacing the matched non-numeric with `''`

Try,

```
$('h1.hole').text(function(_,xText){
 return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QYbU6/)

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, I am a non-native English speaker, I cant get what did you mean.? :)

Comment: Using all-capitals is usually interpreted as shouting when in an online setting; I was wondering *why* you you were shouting 'DEMO' instead of simply using normal writing conventions, 'Demo,' for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could also strip all the non-digit characters (\D or [^0-9]):

> 'abc123cdef4567hij89'.replace(/\D/g, ''); // returns '123456789'

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYbU6/1/)</kbd>